# What is the scope of the numberOfPatrons? Why?

Tags: java, scope

I have the following code

```
public class Restaurant {
    boolean holiday = true;
    public void eat() {
        if( holiday)
        {
            int numberOfPatrons = 50;
            if(numberOfPatrons > 50)
                System.out.println("Great night at the restaurant! ");
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to know the scope of numberOfPatrons, but I don't know what it is or why? It's a question on some homework that I must be overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 1):

`numberOfPatrons` is a variable which is visible only inside the `if` block, and that is its scope of usage, which means you can't use this variable outside `if`.